# Windows 7 deployment via KACE K2000

Tags: windows, deployment

I'm trying to deploy Windows 7 images on a few Latitude E6430s using K2000.

I run Sysprep with `oobe generalize shutdown` options.

I'm able to capture and deploy an image sucessfully, but unfortunately the system that the image is deployed on boots up and Windows is already activated, and I am not prompted to enter the serial key for Windows.

Does anyone know if that has something to do with the OEM version of Windows that these systems come with?

There is some information out there suggesting that the Windows serial numbers are embedded into the hardware… is that true?

Answer (score 1):

You can **not** deploy an OEM copy of Windows using mass deployment technology like KACE. It is a violation of Microsoft's terms of service, not to mention licensing things break like you are seeing now. You need a volume license or KMS key and vanilla Windows 7 media to do this.

If you are deploying an OEM version (I'll use Dell in this example), it is configured to look at an identifier in the BIOS/motherboard to see if it is running on Dell hardware. If it's a Dell image and Dell hardware, it does not require activation.

Really, the simplest way is to get a KMS key, install it on a server, and let the clients have the default key embedded in Windows and be automatically activated by your KMS server.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, some research suggests that people have had some success using
OEM keys and deployment. http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/103437-sysprep-ing-an-oem-windows-7-image-for-wds?page=1 Although, I'm unsure if their results were sustainable. Do you know if KMS can be used with OEM key's?

Comment: Please read our [faq]. Don't treat this as a forum, it's not. You've just posted this *comment* as an answer. I will throw you a bone, though. KMS uses a single key installed on a server. Workstations are left *unkeyed* and call out to that server on your network for activation automatically. The OEM keys don't factor in at all. Call a Microsoft Licensing VAR and talk about this with them.

Comment: Thanks for info, and sorry about posting in the wrong format.